# Prove that one of the numbers k,k+1, . . . ,k+(n-1) is divisible by n.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I'm supposed to figure out:

Let $k$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ and $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$. Prove that one of the numbers $k,k+1, . . . ,k+(n-1)$ is divisible by n.

Any ideas on how I would go about this?

Comment: Clearly, $k$ divides $k$...right?

Comment: Are you asked  to prove that _exactly_ one of the numbers $k,\ldots, k+(n-1)$ is divisible by $k$?

Comment: It must be something like "divisiable by $n$" instead of "divisiable by $k$" otherwise it is trivial.

Comment: My mistake, it would be divisible by n. Not K.

Comment: @Mark: for goodness sake, leave the question up

Comment: Please do not remove the question once it's been answered. I have rolled it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remainder upon division by $n$ is one of $0,1,2,\ldots n-1$. Since you have $n$ numbers to work with, you have $n$ remainders after division by $n$.

If all of the remainders are different, then one of them must be $0$ by the pigeon-hole principle, and hence one of these numbers was divisible by $n$.

Now suppose two of them $k+a$ and $k+b$ have the same remainder, with $0\leq a<b\leq n-1$. Then $(k+b)-(k+a)$ is divisible by $n$, and so $b-a$ is divisible by $n$. But this is impossible since the smallest $b-a$ can be is $1$ and the largest it can be is $n-1$.

Answer (score 2):

The first number in the list is divisible by $k$.

If you want to prove that one of the numbers is divisible by $n$ then here is a hint:

By long division

$$k=qn+r \,.$$
where $0 \leq r <n-1$.

Now if $r=0$ then $k$ is divisible by $n$. Otherwise, what do you need to add to get the next multiple of $n$?

Comment: could you elaborate further on this?